# Getting the Total Pages in an ActiveReports 7 SectionReport

Tags: .net, activereports

I am working with ActiveReports 7 in ASP.NET. From what I've read it looks like section reports never know anything about the total number of pages. I'm using all section reports, is there some kind of workaround that can be used, possibly a way to iterate a property on an object to be able to get the value?

I am looking to be able to display 'Page X out of Y'. You have access to the X in section reports, but cannot get the Y.

I have support looking into it, as they have nothing currently, but curious if anyone here has figured out a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mgaughan

I am assuming that you are talking about ActiveReports 7.  Could you explain this a bit more?  At what time do you want to know the total number of pages? during the report run or after report completion?

Will it be possible to post these questions on ActiveReports 7 Forum too. http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/88/ShowForum.aspx 
Thanks

Comment: Edited my question to answer these questions.

Comment: This article shows how to accomplish page n of m in ActiveReports.  http://www.datadynamics.com/help/activereports6/arHOWDisplayPageNumbersAndReportDates.html

Comment: Wow, I had read that this would not work with a section report, and what I tried always returned 0, but this works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ActiveReport type from ActiveReports 6 and previous versions has been renamed to SectionReport in ActiveReports 7.  This was done to accommodate the new report type, PageReport.

Comment: Datadynamics links are broken

Comment: updated link for documentation is http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arHOWDisplayPageNumbersAndReportDates.html

ar7 forum link is
http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-7/

general forums:
http://our.componentone.com/groups/